# Tracing memory leak in resque-scheduler process on Ruby MRI 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, ruby-1.9.3

I am running resque-scheduler on Ruby MRI 1.9.3 (as part of Rails 3.2.13) environment, and somehow there is a memory leak happening which is driving me nuts. It does not not happen on my MacOS dev machine (running on *exactly* the same environment), but happens on every 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS machine we run on AWS.

On every pass through the resque-scheduler main loop, the heap keeps growing - despite the fact that the used part of the heap remains the same. A sampling of the GC.stat output here, GC.stat invoked right after a GC.start call.

```
GC.stat: {:count=>151, :heap_used=>2424, :heap_length=>4361, :heap_increment=>1937, :heap_live_num=>840924, :heap_free_num=>145061, :heap_final_num=>0}
GC.stat: {:count=>155, :heap_used=>2428, :heap_length=>4368, :heap_increment=>1940, :heap_live_num=>840924, :heap_free_num=>146688, :heap_final_num=>0}
GC.stat: {:count=>159, :heap_used=>2432, :heap_length=>4375, :heap_increment=>1943, :heap_live_num=>840924, :heap_free_num=>148121, :heap_final_num=>0}
GC.stat: {:count=>164, :heap_used=>2437, :heap_length=>4384, :heap_increment=>1947, :heap_live_num=>840924, :heap_free_num=>150347, :heap_final_num=>0}
GC.stat: {:count=>170, :heap_used=>2443, :heap_length=>4395, :heap_increment=>1952, :heap_live_num=>840924, :heap_free_num=>152593, :heap_final_num=>0}
GC.stat: {:count=>176, :heap_used=>2449, :heap_length=>4406, :heap_increment=>1957, :heap_live_num=>840924, :heap_free_num=>155230, :heap_final_num=>0}
GC.stat: {:count=>181, :heap_used=>2454, :heap_length=>4415, :heap_increment=>1961, :heap_live_num=>840924, :heap_free_num=>157266, :heap_final_num=>0}
GC.stat: {:count=>191, :heap_used=>2464, :heap_length=>4433, :heap_increment=>1969, :heap_live_num=>840924, :heap_free_num=>161334, :heap_final_num=>0}
```

As a separate question, none of the RUBY_FREE_MIN, RUBY_HEAP_MIN_SLOTS, RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT env vars seem to have any effect on how the 1.9.3 GC is behaving. As heap_increment also grows, is the problem simply that GC thinks it needs to keep increasing the heap size due to some hardcoded settings?

[EDIT]

Looking at this again, I can see the heap_used is going up. But if I consider the ObjectSpace.count_objects which are printed together with the GC.stat's, it doesn't make sense:

```
GC.stat: {:count=>172, :heap_used=>2438, :heap_length=>4386, :heap_increment=>1948, :heap_live_num=>841064, :heap_free_num=>150208, :heap_final_num=>0}
ObjectSpace.count_objects: {:TOTAL=>991767, :FREE=>92284, :T_OBJECT=>45577, :T_CLASS=>10048, :T_MODULE=>2452, :T_FLOAT=>1038, :T_STRING=>449766, :T_REGEXP=>4537, :T_ARRAY=>213156, :T_HASH=>17273, :T_STRUCT=>591, :T_BIGNUM=>1605, :T_FILE=>6, :T_DATA=>91099, :T_MATCH=>17, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_RATIONAL=>436, :T_NODE=>57652, :T_ICLASS=>4229}
GC.stat: {:count=>173, :heap_used=>2439, :heap_length=>4388, :heap_increment=>1949, :heap_live_num=>840996, :heap_free_num=>150016, :heap_final_num=>0}
ObjectSpace.count_objects: {:TOTAL=>992173, :FREE=>150621, :T_OBJECT=>45073, :T_CLASS=>9922, :T_MODULE=>2452, :T_FLOAT=>636, :T_STRING=>403784, :T_REGEXP=>4502, :T_ARRAY=>207916, :T_HASH=>15856, :T_STRUCT=>591, :T_BIGNUM=>14, :T_FILE=>6, :T_DATA=>89977, :T_MATCH=>17, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_RATIONAL=>63, :T_NODE=>56639, :T_ICLASS=>4103}
```

How did heap_used go up when all the object counts went down?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the resque_scheduler code I traced down the culprit of the memory leak. It is (drumroll) "Object.methods". Poor resque_scheduler is trying to find some hooks on the job it's about to enqueue, and uses reflection for this. I believe the reason we only noticed this on the resque_scheduler is because it is the only daemon that A. runs without forking and B. uses Object.methods.

The following code when ran in irb leaks around 8Mb of memory:

```
(1..1000).each do
  Object.methods
end
```

All the while, from perspective of ruby's object space, no extra memory is being used.

The problem is apparently something related to malloc on the linux image we are using. I compiled the latest ruby 2.1.3 there, and the example above leaks memory just the same. I have then compiled latest 1.9.3(p547) with jemalloc instead of stock malloc, and the example above no longer leaks. So, I believe this to be the solution.

If anyone can shed more light on what they think is going here, that would be great.

Comment: For jemalloc-based ruby, I did:
1. Download/configure/make/install jemalloc (http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/download.html )
2. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=jemalloc_so_path_where_it_was_installed
3. Download ruby 1.9.3p547 source, do "configure -ljemalloc", then make/install

Comment: Man this is a lot to comprehend, as i have a similar problem; a memory leak in Puma on one box, and a memory leak on just the Rails box where resque does it's thing. Any additional light on this after almost a year? I used derailed_benchmarks gem for the Puma leak, no leak in development using production, just when i add Puma.  Then i have this box to figure out and wonder if 2.1.5 using thie jemalloc may be a thing that could help me out. thoughts?

Comment: There are many possible reasons for the memory leak, run the Object.methods loop in your rails console on the server to check if you get a memory leak out of it. If yes then consider using a different MRI build...